# How to create a new html file in windows 10?

Tags: html, windows, file

I want to create a file called "home.html". Since i am using windows, i tried to first create a text file and then rename it to home.html. But after doing so, when i right click and check the properties of home.html, it shows "Type of file" - text(.txt). I want to create a file with html extension. Kindly help me. I am new to html

Comment: Open windows explorer > Select View tab > Select Options > change folder and search options > View > Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types" > Click OK. Now rename your .txt to .html

Comment: In Windows Explorer i cant find "View tab". Can you help me with the same steps in Google Chrome

Comment: By Windows explorer I meant 'My Computer' or 'This PC' where you can see all your hard drives.

Comment: thankyou for the reply

Answer (score 3):

The file is renamed `home.html.txt` because by default the file extension is hidden on windows.

You must start by displaying the extension of the files to rename them correctly.

if you use windows 8,10,11

```
 1. Open File Explorer (open any folder).
 2. Click the View tab.
 3. Select "File name extensions."
 4. Optionally, you can enable Hidden items.
 5. File extensions will now be visible.
```

[image]

If you use windows 7

```
1. In the Start menu search, type folder options.
2. In the Folder Options window, click the View tab.
3. Remove the check from "Hide extensions for known file types."
4. Click OK.
```

SOURCE : [https://knowledge.autodesk.com](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-enable-hidden-file-extensions-in-Windows.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can create that file using **CMD**,

1. Open CMD
2. Tape the following command in the location you want to create the file

```sh
type nul > file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In the desktop window of your PC create a new folder ( with any name) double click on the folder to enter, then right click and create a new txt file. After creating a txt file, right click on it, then select rename and change the .txt to .html to make it a HTML file.

Comment: Why do you need a new folder?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue . What you need to do is that you gonna go to your editor be it NotePad or Sublime . Press ctrl N for a new page and Ctrl S to save the file and you will need to choose your file type to be html

Answer (score -2):

You need to open notepad on your PC and write your HTML code.

Then go in 'File', 'Save as',write the file name with the .html `example: name.html`.

Now change `.txt` to 'all files'.

Comment: I do not have an html code to start with. I just want to create an empty file with html extension. I created a text file and renamed it to home.html. I went to "Save as" and renamed the file as home.html. I also changed .txt to "all files". Now i tried to open this home.html in ATOM TEXT EDITOR. when i select home.html and open it in Atom Text Editor it opens as "home.html.txt". When i right clicked on "home.html" and clicked properties, it is showing "File type - .txt"

Comment: You should create the file without writing ".html", you have to write ".html" only after selecting "all files"